# How to access an outer member from a nested object literal?

Tags: javascript, scope, nested, object-literal

In the following code, can the x member be accessed from the nested object literal?

```
var outer = {
    x : 0,
    inner: {
        a : x + 1,       // 'x' is undefined.
        b : outer.x + 1, // 'outer' is undefined.
        c : this.x + 1   // This doesn't produce an error, 
    }                    // but outer.inner.c is NaN.
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Not sure whether it can at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the way you put it - no.

You need two stages construction, this will work:

```
var outer = { x : 0 };
// outer is constructed at this point.
outer.inner = {
        b : outer.x + 1 // 'outer' is defined here.
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Not in the construct you have there, no.

The main reason being that `outer` doesn't actually exist yet when you are inside `inner`.

If you changed the properties of `inner` to functions you could access `outer` at runtime, but it would be pretty ugly code.

Consider using `new outer();` instead and build an object that way, then you can use `this` inside `inner`, but then that is a completely different construct and would look something like

```
var outer = function() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.inner = {
        a: this.x + 1
    };                    
};

var b = new outer();

console.log(b.inner.a); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that sort of construct would make sense. I don't think there's anything stopping you from saying

```
var outer2;
outer2.inner = outer.inner;
```

In that scenario, how would you distinguish between the two parents?

The way to do it is probably with more of a constructor type function, with a parameter that gets assigned to outer.x and inner.whatever as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a closure:

```
var outer = function outer() {

    var x = 0;   

    return {
       inner : {
           a: x + 1
           }
       }                   
};

var b = outer();
console.log('a is ' + b.inner.a);
//a is 1
```

For a great article on closures check out **the javascript garden**

http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#closures